# Как правильно сделать рекурсию?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Нашел задачку в которой нужно число разложить на составляющие числа и сплюсовать их, если в этом числе будет больше 1-го элемента сделать тоже самое. Но я не до конца понимаю как реализовать рекрсию, вроде написал, а оно не работает.
Кто может объяснить вместо чего подставляется мой d_root в строке digital_root(d_root)?

```
def digital_root(n):
    n = str(n)
    d_root = 0
    for num in n:
        d_root += int(num)
    if len(str(d_root)) > 1:
        digital_root(d_root)
    else:
        return d_root

print(digital_root(29))
```

29 -> 11 -> 2    # 2 + 9 = 11 = 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: Не обязательно рекурсией решить, но я решил попробовать использовать её и не до конца понимаю что она подставляет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка построения рекурсии в строке `digital_root(d_root)` - значение не возвращается.

Cледовало написать `return digital_root(d_root)`, потому что при рекурсии происходит спуск цепочкой до самого начального значения, которое называется "базой рекурсии", а в случае если происходит обычный вызов функции, вместо возврата ее значения, то на самой вершине стека вызовов об итоговом результате работы никак узнают и возвратится `None`.

**P.S** Я бы переписал эту функцию чуть более просто:

```
def digital_root(n):
    sum_digits = sum(map(int, str(n)))
    if sum_digits > 9:
        return digital_root(sum_digits)
    return sum_digits


print(digital_root(29)) # 2
```

Либо в одну строку:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(map(int, str(n))))
```

**P.P.S** А вообще, это очень известная задача, и для нее есть красивые математические решения без рекурсии, например:

```
def digital_root(n):
    if n % 9 == 0 and n != 0:
        return 9
    return n % 9
```

И даже вот такое :)

```
def digital_root(n):
    return 1 + (n - 1) % 9
```